# Path issue with autoload function to get files for use in Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, path

So my project uses an MVC framework and I have a page with an Ajax script I run to get content from the server.  When the PHP script is called in the Ajax script, I want to access the classes already in my library for use in the PHP script.  To do this, I use what I call an ajaxBootstrap to call the appropriate function that then instantiates the objects needed for that specific Ajax script.

To load those classes from my library I have an autoload function in my ajaxBootstrap so I don't need to use a bunch of require and include statements.  My problem is those files aren't being loaded due to a path issue with the autoload function.  When I use a require statement with the same path, the classes load with no problems, its only when I try to load them using the autoload function that I get an 500 internal server error.

Here is my ajaxBootstrap file:

```
// This file routes Ajax requests made in JS files and instantiates a specific object to carry out the actions needed for that particular Ajax operation 

// Autoload any classes that are required
function autoLoad($classToLoad)
{
    if(file_exists('../library/' . $classToLoad . 'class.php')) // File in the library folder
    {
        require('../library/' . $classToLoad . '.class.php');
   }
    else if(file_exists('../../app/models/' . $classToLoad . 'class.php')) // File in the models folder
    {
        require('../../app/models/' . $classToLoad . '.class.php');
    }
}

spl_autoload_register('autoLoad');

// Determine which function to call based on the url that's listed in the Ajax request
switch($_GET['action'])
{
    case 'pageOne':
        pageOne();
        break;
    case 'pageTwo':
        pageTwo();
        break;
}

function pageOne()
{
    $test = new Test();
    $test->funcThatReturnStuff();
}

function pageTwo()
{
    $test2 = new Test2();
    $test2->funcThatReturnStuff();
}
```

Like I mentioned eariler, if I use a require statement such as:

```
require('../library/Test.class.php');
$test = new Test();
$test->funcThatReturnStuff();
```

The class loads and works just fine.  But using the same path in the autoloader function throws an error.  The really odd thing is if I put an else if statement in the autoloader that loads a class from the folder where my ajaxBootstrap is it also works fine too...

I know I could just use the require statements and be done with the problem but I want to be able to scale the project and not need to use loads of require statements in the future.  BTW, I use '../' to get from where my ajaxBootstrap file is to my other folders.

Also, to add to my previous post, I've tried replacing the `../` with absolute paths using `define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__) . '/')` and also `define('ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/path/to/folder/')` neither of which worked and still gave me the internal server error in Firebug.  In addition, I haven't received any errors in my error log either.

Comment: Have you tried using absolute paths (including `__DIR__` or `dirname(__FILE__)`)? AFAIR there are some issues with cascading relativ includes.

Comment: @apfelbox Yes, I've tried replacing ../ with `define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__) . '/')` and even tried using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` but I still get the same problem...

Comment: I would guess it is related to this [PHP bug posting](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=9673). Could you add the complete error message to your post?

Comment: @apfelbox The error in FireBug is: NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost/path/to/file

Comment: @apfelbox I just read through the link you provided and I'm wondering if the relative path bug is somehow messing up inside of the file_exists() because like I mentioned, using the require statement with the same path works fine.

Comment: Do you get an actual error message out of PHP (like in the error log or with display_errors=on)?

Comment: No, just the internal server error in Firebug.

Comment: Well, the apache is configured to send a 500 error page in case it encounters an error. You should activate error logging and actually look at the messages. Also, could you post your version using absolute paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind...  Even after staring at my code for the past few hours I somehow missed the missing period in two of my file paths.  I hate coding sometimes...  Thank you to anyone who took time to read this.